# Implementing ach with stripe in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I took the customers bank details and converted into token .Based on that token I created the customer id .Next I need to do the verifySource . but I am getting error at verifySource , error is 
 **

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'verifySource' of
>   undefined**

** **Here is My code is****

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_73xfGiaFaZLWO8oVoNr8PqSe");
var tokenId = "btok_1BiIZkKB2GdGniJfVf8H0Yy0";
var data = {amounts: [32,45]}
// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
//var token = request.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
// Create a Customer:
stripe.customers.create({
  email: "paying1.user@example.com",
  source: tokenId,
}).then(function(customer) {
  // YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.
   stripe.customer.verifySource(
   tokenId,
  customer.id,
  {
    amounts: [32,45]
    },
   function(err, bankAccount) {
   });
   });
```

Please help me out .After verifySource what is the next step to process.
How to verify the user bank accounts

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `stripe.customers` instead of `stripe.customer`

Comment: Thanks Titus , error is resolved .but were I need to see the resultant output .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Titus pointed out, you have a typo in your code: `stripe.customer.verifySource` should be `stripe.customers.verifySource` instead.

Additionally, `verifySource` expects a bank account ID (`ba_...`), not a bank account *token* ID (`btok_...`). Also the customer ID should be the first argument and the bank account ID should be the second argument (cf. [the API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#customer_verify_bank_account)).

Try upgrading your code like this:

```
stripe.customers.create({
  email: "paying1.user@example.com",
  source: tokenId,
}).then(function(customer) {
  // YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.
  stripe.customers.verifySource(
    customer.id,
    customer.sources.data[0].id,
    {
      amounts: [32, 45]
    }
  ).then(function(bankAccount) {
  });
});
```

Comment: customer.sources.data[0].id, this line what  action performs

Comment: It returns the ID of the bank account that was added as the customer's payment source. Cf. https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-sources and https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_bank_account_object